# nginx rewrite: the symbol for ANY UTF8 character

Tags: regex, web-services, url-rewriting, nginx

I want to know what symbol I can use to refer to any character within the utf8 encoding table for nginx rewriting. I have tried:

```
rewrite ^/.$ /new-location.html break;
```

but it seems the "." can only stand for ascii characters, when I tried http://example.com/汉 (a Chinese character), it did not work.

This also does not work:

```
rewrite ^/([\x00-\xff])$ /new-location.html break;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation :

> However,  UTF-8  and  Unicode  support has to be
>          explicitly enabled; it is not the default. The  Unicode  tables  corre-
>          spond to Unicode release 6.0.0.

So you have to enable utf-8 to work :

```
"(*UTF8)^yourregex$"
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but I got error msg: [emerg]: `pcre_compile() failed: (*VERB) not recognized in "^(*UTF8)/(.)$" at "8)/(.)$" in xxx `.

Comment: Hm OK. There are these two directive you may want to put into your config file. `charset utf8;
 source_charset utf8;`

Comment: I have already done that. Maybe it is my PCRE (version 7.8 2008-09-05) does not support the (*UTF8) argument. I am trying to upgrade it. With Ubuntu, will `apt-get upgrade libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` upgrade my PCRE?

Comment: I am not an ubuntu expert so I can't help you here. :). However if specify the charset then the . should match all characters, including utf-8 ones.

Comment: I did it. I upgraded my PCRE and (*UTF8) works now. If you read Chinese, this article will help you on how to upgrade PCRE for Nginx: http://www.cslog.cn/Content/nginx-pcre-utf8-rewrite/

Answer (score 3):

The instruction above tells you to use...

```
"(*UTF8)^yourregex$"
```

but your error message reveals you're using something different...

```
"^(*UTF8)/(.)$"
```

I'm no expert, but it looks like you've been advised to *prefix* your regex with (*UTF8) but instead you're inserting it *after* the opening character of your regex.