# Does anyone know whether regex based location checks support Unicode properties?

Tags: regex, nginx, unicode

I have other things to do, so I can't play with it right now and someone of you might know and gain some credibility points here. So, the question is:

There are [extensions for Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories) that allow the testing of characters by properties. For example `\p{L}` would match any character that is categorized as a letter in any script. Does the regex engine that nginx uses support theses expressions? The nginx docs do not seem to mention anything in this regards.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126872/what-regular-expression-engine-does-nginx-use

Comment: Maybe also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950575/9758194)